# duplicate entry in R generated class android

Tags: android

i have this line

```
  public static final int text_view222=0x7f060077;
```

in my `R.java` file duplicate and cause error in my android application  , any body know how to fix this.
UPDATE :

i have aslo other R file from another projects that came when i add them as a library project ..

Comment: u have try after Cleaning project from Project->Clean.. on Eclipse IDE

Comment: I don't know why this got downvoted as I got really helped by it. Also, I think that the tools should check for valid ID's.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

i face this problem before and after spending 1 hour i found that i have a `TextView` which it id have a  `space` character before the `id` name and another `TextView` without the space . so in you case you have this some where in your layout files.
look at the space before the id name.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/ text_view222"
...
...
..
/>
```

and another one  without space

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/text_view222"
...
...
..
/>
```

Comment: the problem can also occur, if you are referring to this textview with space in its id like `layout_above="@+id/text_view222    "`. One should also remember to check references if this is the error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the problem with duplicate localization strings. There was indeed a space behind the key in one of the _.string_ files (`<string name="resource_key ">String</string>`).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. My mistake was in two xml. file i have puted the following

```
android:id="@+id/ETclienteNuevoDireccion"
```

and another:

```
android:id="@+id/ETclienteNuevoDireccion "
```

I only had a space more to the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the file and then clean the project. Project > Clean...

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your `R.java` file.
2. Do a <kbd>Project</kbd> --> <kbd>Clean</kbd>
3. Restart eclipse.
4. `R.java` should automatically re-build (assuming there are no errors in your project).

Comment: i have also other R files came into project when i add them as a library

Comment: Maybe try deleting the whole gen folder?

Comment: There's probably an error in your xml somewhere... either that or you have not correctly referenced your 3rd party library? Do you have any spaces in your ids? This apparently will cause a "duplicate id" error.

Comment: @user4o01, are you positive that your layouts don't contain duplicate id names?